# Titanium - Can not build my project when using 7.0.2

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator

I can't build my project on IOS when using 7.0.2 ! please how I can fix this problem.

> [INFO] :   Invoking xcodebuild
>
> [ERROR] :  ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> [ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
>
> [ERROR] :      Ld build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/app.app/app normal x86_64
>
> [ERROR] :  (1 failure)

Comment: which XCode version are you using? If its not the latest please update (9.2)

Comment: mmm ok, thank you @miga

Comment: I don't think you're really using 7.0.2GA; the latest version is 7.0.2 RC, which was released on January 25, 2018.  You should edit your question (and especially the subject) so as not to confuse readers.